# Get url address with regex

Tags: regex, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I'm trying to get the following url address www.salesforce.co.uk out of this String:

`'raewaferwww.salesforce.co.ukhrewadfea'`.

For that reason I've created the following regex:

`https?://www.|https?|www.)([A-Za-z\\d._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&\'()*+,;=-]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+[.][A-Za-z]{2,3}`

The returned result is:

`www.salesforce.co.ukh`

What I would like to know is how to remove the 'h' character and have the proper 
`www.salesforce.co.uk` url address?

Could you please advise how this can be achieved?

Comment: Because `{2,3}` allows three characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Washington Guedes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4227915/washington-guedes) mentions, `{2,3}` will match either 2 or 3 characters.

Changing to `{2}` will give you just `www.salesforce.co.uk`

**However**: If your intent is to match other urls that end in a 3-letter TLD, switching to `{2}` will not meet your overall needs.

In order to match both 2-letter TLDs (.uk, .to, etc) **and** 3-letter TLDs (.com, .net, etc) from a string of letters, you will need to match against the TLDs specifically, and check for 3-letters before 2-letters (otherwise `.com` would be matched as `.co`)